# SQL Server : is it possible to create non-clustered index for IS NULL condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

What will be the syntax to create non-clustered index for the query which has `is null` condition.

Sample query:

```
select * 
from mytable
where mycolumn is null
```

Index that I created:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [myindexname]
ON [dbo].[mytable] ([mycolumn])
```

When I execute this query in SQL and see its execution plan, it shows missing index.

[image]

Or there any other, alternative possibilities?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem creating indexes on nullable columns.
The only thing you can't do with nullable columns is create a primary key.

You can right click the green message and SSMS will give you the option to copy it. Then paste it into the query editor and you will see it contains the create index statement. All you need to do is give it it's name and run the statement.

Following the conversation in the comments to this answer, Ivan Sivak have figured out that this is a bug that SQL Server had in and was fixed in 2012 version.
[Here is the link to the bug report in Microsoft Connect.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/400578/query-plan-missing-index-recommendation-doesnt-check-if-an-index-actually-exists)

Comment: Yes, i have done exactly the same. The image that i have attached in my question is after the index creation.

Comment: Sometimes, after creating the missing index, the optimizer can recommend another missing index. See if it's the same index that you just created.

Comment: @Namita What version of SQL Server do you use? Is the suggested index really absolutely identical with your originally created one?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2 and ssms version: 10.50.1600.1 and in the suggested index i've updated only name of my index

Comment: Also, the column on which i want to create index is "bigint" and it is a nullable column.(Hope this info helps)

Comment: @Namita There was a bug in SQL Server that was fixed from v.2012. Check this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1641792-3387-1.aspx

Comment: @IvanSivak In that case, I would suggest you post the explanation as an answer, with the link to microsoft's bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/400578/query-plan-missing-index-recommendation-doesnt-check-if-an-index-actually-exists. I would be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's alright ;) Please feel free to edit your answer and mention the link as a potential cause.

Comment: @IvanSivak Done.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the query plan uses the best index in available in any scenario.

One reason could be that the index is **fragmented**.
 You could decrease the fragmentation by running the query

```
ALTER INDEX [myindexname] ON [dbo].[mytable] REBUILD;
```

> You can read more on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes

The query plan at times doesn't take the best available index for the query. For this, Microsoft has provided table hints.

1. **ForceSeek**
   This tells the optimizer to use an index seek operation in any case.

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable WITH(FORCESEEK)
WHERE  mycolumn IS NULL
```

> Caution: while using any Force Plan hint (ForceSeek,ForceScan,etc.) or you might break the query

2. **Index Hint**
   This tells the optimizer to use a particular index for seek/scan

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable WITH([myindexname])
WHERE  mycolumn IS NULL
```

This query will now use **myindexname** for above query.

3. You can **combine** both these hints:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable WITH([myindexname], ForceSeek)
WHERE  mycolumn IS NULL
```

This query will now use **myindexname** with a *scan* operation for above query.

> More on table hints here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510478(v=sql.105).aspx